What is this strange Texas tree?
This is located in Lubbock, Texas. The tree seems to be on the smaller side and is wildly invasive. The neighbor's yard is filled with them, and they seem happy to try to grow in mine... I suspect through some root system, as they just pop up. The leaves are small-toothed on the edges, mostly heart/teardrop shaped, but occasionally two-lobed (mitten shape), or three-lobed (thumbs on both sides). One or two leaves (just) seem to be many, many lobed, but I can't tell if those are just mutant growth or normal. I am familiar with sassafras (grew up in Indiana), and those the leaves are sort of the same shapes, definitely not that. Some pictures/descriptions on the internet suggest mulberry looks like this, but I have never seen fruit in many years.






Good leaf pictures. A bark picture might also be helpful; from what you say no fruit (or presumably flower) picture is likely, but bark should be.

@Ecnerwal Will try to get a picture of bark, but most of the stuff on my property is still small, so not sure what kind of quality I can provide. Will put something up this evening. Wife says that she thinks she remembers some sort of fruit on these, so maybe the drought just ruined them the last couple years. But even if there is some, not sure when I could expect it to grow so that I can get pictures.

Its inability to produce fruits can be a sign of disease

@SnackExchange Or I'm just wrong about what it is. Not exactly Forest Ranger Bob, ya know? But running a test here soon that is considered conclusive. Bought my kids some silkworm eggs, those will hatch soon. They'll either eat it or starve, and I guess they know better than any of us what's what. Apparently there are some fruitless cultivars. And Wikipedia suggests sometimes they're dioecious... this could just be one giant colony of male plants. Will return with a definitive answer in a few weeks, if no one beats me to it.

@JohnO I gave the pictures to a plant identification app called Plantnet. First I tried with the leafs and second with the bark image. In all cases the plant was 58% identified to be Broussonetia papyrifera (with the common name Paper Mulberry).

@SnackExchange I agree. It does look very much like what I see in my yard. The good news is, I suppose, several forum posts claim the little silkworms like this almost as much as white mulberry, so I don't have to deal with disappointed kids. Thanks Snack.
